# GCE won’t allow me to connect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, remote, google

When I attempt to remote into my server through Windows Remote Desktop I get an error and it won’t allow me to establish connection to my server.

Answer (score 2):

To connect to GCE Windows VM through Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) you need to add a firewall rule that allows to establish TCP connection on RDP port (`3389` by default):

```sh
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-rdp --allow tcp:3389
```

You can find additional information about RDP connection troubleshooting in [GCE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-rdp).

Answer (score 0):

I would however be a little more careful and only allow it from your own external IP at the very least - or preferably using something like Identity aware proxy (IAP) :

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/cloud-iap-enables-context-aware-access-to-vms-via-ssh-and-rdp-without-bastion-hosts